# Clementine appears in two PPAs. How can I specify which one to use?

Tags: apt, clementine

The clementine package in 12.04 lacks spotify support. So I added the clementine PPA like this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:me-davidsansome/clementine
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install clementine
```

Then I installed like this:

```
sudo apt-get install clementine=1.0.1~precise
```

Because that's the version in the clementine-specific PPA. But now the update manager wants to update to the version from the ubuntu archive because it's newer.

How can I tell it to maintain clementine from the clementine PPA, not the ubuntu PPA?

I realize similar questions have been asked but not exactly this, and I can't figure it out, so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Much more helpful than locking would be pinning Clementine to the PPA.  This would do exactly what you want - ensure that apt always prefers the version of Clementine that's in the PPA.  Pinning is awesome if you do it correctly.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

With Synaptic you can "force" the installation of a package different from the one chosen by Synaptic. Do the following:

1. Click Reload or press Ctrl + R to make Synaptic aware of the latest updates.
2. Select the package. Choose Force Version from the Package menu.
3. Select the version you would like to use. To confirm your decision, click Force.
4. Click Apply on the toolbar or press Ctrl + P. A dialog appears with a summary of the changes that will be made to your system. To confirm, press Apply.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Unfortunately it doesn't work. It installs okay, but the update manager continues to insist on "updating" to the ubuntu version (which is newer).

Comment: Then you may want to LOCK version (not FORCE). Follow these instructions: http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-lock-package-versions-from-synaptic-package-manager.html

Comment: Ok, that works, thank you. Ideally I would like it to update to new versions that are posted in the Clementine PPA... rather than have it locked. But at least it's working for now. Thanks.